# Регулярное выражения для поиска пары ключ-значение с и без кавычек

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно с помощью регулярки найти пару ключ-значение, записанных в виде:

```
key="value" или key=value
```

И выделить отдельно ключ, отдельно значение без кавычек.

```
для key="value" -> key value
для key=value -> key value
```

На данный момент пользуюсь такой:

```
([^=,]*)=("[^"]*"|[^,"]*)
```

Но она выделяет `"value"` полностью, вместе с кавычками.

Comment: Какой язык? Пользуйтесь `([^=,]*)=(?|"([^"]*)"|([^,"]*))`, если вы пишете на PHP

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, работает отлично, вы очень помогли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать группу со сбросом нумерации захватывающих подмасок `(?|...|...)`:

```
([^=,]*)=(?|"([^"]*)"|([^,"]*))
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/q9C5Vr/1).

**Подробности**

- `([^=,]*)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: 0 и более символов, отличных от `=` и `,`
- `=` -  символ `=`
- `(?|` - начало группы со сбросом нумерации захватывающих подмасок

  - `"` - `"`
  - `([^"]*)` - Захватывающая подмаска **№2**: 0 и более символов, отличных от `"`
  - `"` - символ `"`
  - `|` - или
  - `([^,"]*)` - Захватывающая подмаска **№2**: 0 и более символов, отличных от `,` и
  - `"` - символ `"`
- `)` - конец  группы со сбросом нумерации захватывающих подмасок